# How to setup Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta to watch make compile scss automatically?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, sass, bootstrap-4, npm-install

So I am trying to setup Bootstrap v4 Beta, But I don't understand, How to setup Watch task, On Bootstrap version 3 they had Grunt Watch, What should I do setup custom watch task or they have already had that built in like before.

Comment: For starters, add as much  information as you can. Things you have already tried. Try to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a BS4 beginner, but maybe here?
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/build-tools/#using-npm-scripts

Comment: Yes, I tried them but none of them watch and auto compile the process, I'll have to compile code each time manually.

Answer (score 0):

I use Scout-App to compile them automatically for me. Or, GULP can accomplish for you as well, but it's more difficult to use/set up. As far as Grunt Watch, never used it.